# Attribute Table Subtract Value From Previous Value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, table

I have a river shapefile and need to ensure every vertice has a lower elevation that the previous uphill vertice.

I have converted the polylineZ to points using ET GeoWizards.

This gives me a Z value for every vertice.

I have added a field called ElevDiff.

I need to calculate the difference in elevation values from the previous vertice to the next in the attribute table.

If the value is negative, I know the line does not flow downhill at this point.

This is an easy task in Excel but I am wondering if there is a python script or easy way to calculate this using ArcGIS.

I do not have any extensions (i.e. Spatial Analyst, 3D Analyst, Newtwork Analyst).

Comment: Have you considered using slope for the river segments instead? A python script could do it the way you are asking (row 2 - row 1) using cursors but I would be cautious since you have to be clear which vertice is upstream/downstream, for example if you have a confluence you have two upstream points. Do you have a field for upstream ID? What version of arc are you using?

Comment: I had thought of using slope but I didn't know how to access the vertices along a line. I am using the basic version of Arc 10.2.2. I have been trying to piece together python codes with no luck as I do not have much experience doing that. I can find where the river segment flows uphill in Excel, but would like to do this in Arc using Python. I received the lines from a fellow employee who generated them in MicroStation. I do not have a field for upstream ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be extremely cautious assuming the order of the vertices (FID) in the table goes in the order of your river flow. If you had an order_ID this could be set up to use that instead. I'm not familiar with ET Geo Wizard, if your points have the elevations in a field rather than as z values replace "SHAPE@Z" with that field name.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import da
vertices = "File_Name.shp"
elev1=0
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(vertices, ["FID", "SHAPE@Z", "ElevDiff"]) as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
          elev2 = float(row[1])
          row[2] = (elev1 - elev2)
          elev1 = elev2
          cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. ET GeoWizards is a free extension for Arc. It did add an order_ID along the line field I was able to use for the calculation. For "File_Name.shp" I had to remove the ".shp" in order for the tool to run. I am now attempting to build this as a script/tool in ArcToolbox in order to put this in a larger model. I have created a new toolbox, added the script from above, but cannot figure out how to make the "File_Name.shp" a variable. I need it to match the name of the input parameter in the script GUI. Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, make sure to accept the answer to show it as solved. Are you using [arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Accessing_parameters_in_a_script_tool/001500000007000000/)? Or parameters[0].valueAsText in a .pyt? If its not a quick fix you might want to post your code as a new question.