# ArcGIS calculate difference between rows in the same field that is date time format

Tags: python, arcpy, attribute-table, datetime

I'm looking for help tweaking the python code discussed here: [Attribute Table Subtract Value From Previous Value](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122429/attribute-table-subtract-value-from-previous-value)

I'm having trouble figuring out how to adjust it for a date field in which I want to subtract a time by the previous time to get gaps.  Here is what I have so far and the error received:

```
import arcpy

from arcpy import da

vertices ="CBR05_T2_10_1_2014_WLanduse_1"
gap1=0
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(vertices, ["INDEX_", "Time", "GapDiff"]) as cursor:

    for row in cursor:
        gap2 = row[1]
        row[2] = datetime(gap2 - gap1)
        gap1 = gap2
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Runtime error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 8, in 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'

Comment: Please **edit** the question to format the Python code using four leading spaces, and without the extraneous periods.  It should have correct indentation.

Comment: In the first iteration of your for loop, you're subtracting an integer object (`gap1=0`) from a datetime object. Update the code to skip the subtract for the first loop. something like `firstRow = True` outside of the loop, then in the loop `if firstRow == True:` `firstRow = False` `gap1 = gap2` `else:` `row[2] = datetime (gap2 - gap1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to subtract an integer (defined at `gap1=0`) from a datetime object in the following line: `row[2] = datetime(gap2 - gap1)`. You'll need to skip the first row and assign its datetime to a variable for the next row. Since the first row has no proceeding datetime, it won't get a value updated.

This worked for me:

```
import arcpy

from arcpy import da

vertices ="CBR05_T2_10_1_2014_WLanduse_1"

#set firstRow variable to true
firstRow = True

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(vertices, ["INDEX_", "Time", "GapDiff"]) as cursor:

    for row in cursor:
        gap2 = row[1]

        #check if its the first row
        if firstRow == True:
            gap1 = gap2
            #set firstrow to false
            firstRow = False
            continue
        row[2] = str(gap2 - gap1)
        gap1 = gap2
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Note that the "GapDiff" field needs to be a string field. a datetime field doesn't support time values resulting from a subtration (such as `1 day`).

Comment: Great! this worked really well as I know very little python...

Comment: Great. If you could mark my answer as the correct one then by clicking the check mark I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious if there was a cleaner way to use cursors without having to always use the `firstRow` check, and it turns out the following works. Hooray for generators*!

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "OID@") as cursor:
    p = cursor.next()[0] #previous
    for row in cursor:
        c = row[0] #current
        print(c - p) #function goes here to update values
        p = row[0] #becomes previous next iteration
```

Without knowing what your data looks like or how you want the `GapDiff` field populated (string, int, date, etc.), you'll need to come up with a function.

*Since `cursor` is a generator, `next(cursor)` also works, as does calling the `.reset()` method on it to start from the beginning.